# Plot of recurring system in MATLAB, Lozi map

Tags: recurrence-relations, matlab, systems-of-equations

I need to write this recurring system in MATLAB 
$$ x_{n+1}=1-a|x_n|+y_n$$
$$ y_{n+1}=bx_n $$
and take its plot for every $x_i,y_i$,with let's say a=1.4 and b=0.7.
$$$$This is the Lozi map. And this link might help:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LoziMap.html

Thanks in advance and hope for your help!

Comment: First you shouldn't try to compute $\infty$ many iterations. Then: what's the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I put a stop button so as to stop it when i want and rec function, but doesn t work properly.
I am not an expert in matlab thought. I know basics.

Comment: Then first try to terminate after a fixed number of iterations, no fancy stuff. Just produce the $N\times1$-vectors x,y and plot them.

Comment: while ~get(stop,'value')$$$$

  solve(rec (x(n+1) - 1+a*abs(x(n))-b*x(n), x(n+1),{x(0)==1} ))
$$$$        y(n+1)=b*x(n);$$$$
plot(x(n+1), y(n+1))$$$$
end$$$$

have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
function [x,y]=lozi(n,a,b,x1,y1)
    x=zeros(n,1);
    y=x;
    x(1) = x1;
    y(1) = y1;
    for k=2:n
        x(k) = 1 - a*abs(x(k-1)) + y(k-1);
        y(k) = b*x(k-1);
    end
end
```

Then call the function with desired parameters and plot the result.

Comment: By calling "plot" with linespec I get only points. Is there a way to join them in line, in order to get this Lozi map plot?

Comment: @maria Does this work: `line([x(k-1) x(k)], [y(k-1) y(k)])`?

Comment: Yes! this lines correctly the points ! thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
function [x,y]=lozi(n,a,b,x1,y1)
    x=zeros(n,1);
    y=x;
    x(1) = x1;
    y(1) = y1;
    for k=2:n
        x(k) = 1 - a*abs(x(k-1)) + y(k-1);
        y(k) = b*x(k-1);
    end
end
```

then run using

```
[x,y] = lozi(5000,1.4, 0.3, -0.5, -0.2);
 plot(x,y,'.','markersize',2);
```